# Implement a generic comparer with two clases that doesn't implement any interface

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, software-design

I'm developing an Angular app with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and C#

Most of my controllers have this method:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public void Save([FromBody] List<Models.LinePresentation> lines)
{
    bool hasChanges = false;

    List<Models.LinePresentation> newLines = 
        lines
            .Where(l => l.LineId == 0)
            .ToList();

    if ((newLines != null) && (newLines.Count > 0))
    {
        hasChanges = true;

        foreach(Models.LinePresentation newLine in newLines)
        {
            Line newDbLine = new Line()
            {
                LineReferenceId = newLine.LineReferenceId,
                Name = newLine.Name
            };

            _context.Line.Add(newDbLine);
        }
    }

    List<Line> currentLines = _context.Line.ToList();

    foreach (Line dbLine in currentLines)
    {
        Models.LinePresentation modLine = 
            lines.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LineId == dbLine.LineId);

        if (modLine == null)
        {
            _context.Line.Remove(dbLine);

            if (!hasChanges)
                hasChanges = true;
        }
        else if ((dbLine.LineReferenceId != modLine.LineReferenceId) ||
                    (dbLine.Name != modLine.Name))
        {
            dbLine.LineReferenceId = modLine.LineReferenceId;
            dbLine.Name = modLine.Name;

            _context.Line.Update(dbLine);

            if (!hasChanges)
                hasChanges = true;
        }
    }

    if (hasChanges)
        _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I could change classes `Models.LinePresentation` and `Line` and use it with two generic classes.

And I think I could change the DbSet `_context.Line` with a generic DbSet like `DbSet<T>` (or maybe I'm wrong).

My problem here if that I have to compare `Line` with `LinePresentation`. Like I did in the code:

```
else if ((dbLine.LineReferenceId != modLine.LineReferenceId) ||
         (dbLine.Name != modLine.Name))
```

These classes are:

```
public class Line : IEquatable<Line>
{
    public int LineId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LineReferenceId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Batch> Batch { get; set; }
}

public class LinePresentation
{
    public int LineId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LineReferenceId { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way to create an Interface to compare these two classes?

I don't think so because `Line` and `LinePresentation` doesn't implement any interface and I don't want to use reflection.

Comment: What do you mean by *compare*? Test for value semantics equality?

Comment: I have updated the question with the meaning of compare. It's like I did in this piece of code: `else if ((dbLine.LineReferenceId != modLine.LineReferenceId) || (dbLine.Name != modLine.Name))`

Comment: I got lost at the part "the other problem here if that I have to compare..." I thought that *was* the question. Once I read that I started scanning the first half of the post again trying to figure out what the first problem was. If there are two problems it's better to ask two questions.

Comment: @ScottHannen Then, there is only one problem: how to create a generic class to know that `Line` and `LinePresentation` have all of their properties with the same values.

Comment: Well if you don't want to use reflection in any form and don't want to implement common interface - there is not much you can do besides what you already doing.

Answer (score 0):

If your `LinePresentation` is presentation-layer entity and `Line` is business domain entity then it's not a good practice to directly compare them. You better **convert your LinePresentation to Line first via some converter and them implement comparer on domain entities**.

Despite `Line` and `LinePresentation` are very similar classes, from my experience it is **not very convenient to make them implement some common interface** e.g. `ILine` because it makes the whole idea of separating layers useless (the idea was to vary presentation from domain and from storage independently wasn't it?). Sooner or later you'll want to change your presentation and you wouldn't be able to do that without affecting business entity and, possibly, DB entity if all implement same interface.

So I suggest your code look like

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public void Save([FromBody] List<Models.LinePresentation> lines)
{
    Save(lines.Select(l=>new Line {LineId = l.LineId, Name = l.Name, LineReferenceId = l.LineReferenceId}))
}

private void Save(IEnumerable<Line> lines)
{
    // Most of your code goes here slightly modified to work with business objects
}
```

Later, method `Save(IEnumerable<Line>)` can be extracted to business layer logic and possibly reused across your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is provide a method that checks for "equality" in the sense of equal properties, you can do that with an extension method so that you don't have to modify either class.

```
public static class LineExtensions
{
    public static bool Matches(this Line line, LinePresentation presentation)
    {
        return line.LineReferenceId == presentation.LineReferenceId
               && line.Name == presentation.Name;
    }
}
```

This isn't technically different from what you're doing now. It just moves it around, removes some potential duplication, and might make it a little more readable since the name of the extension method can communicate the intent.

Comment: Your answer allows to reuse the `Matches` code without writing it again but, how can I use an extension method with a generic class? If I create a Generic method with generic classes for `Line` and `LinePresentation`, I don't think that the compiler allows me to use something like `T1.Maches(T2)`. Or maybe there is another way to do it. Thanks.